# prove that $\tan(\alpha+\beta) = 2ac/(a^2-c^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

if $\alpha$ , $\beta$  are the values of  $\theta$ satisfying  $$\displaystyle a\tan(\theta)+b\sec(\theta) = c$$

prove that $$\displaystyle\tan(\alpha+\beta) = \dfrac{2ac}{a^2-c^2}$$
How do i solve this, suggestions about how to go about doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$b\sec\theta=c-a\tan\theta$$

Squaring we get  $$(c-a\tan\theta)^2=(b\sec\theta)^2=b^2(1+\tan^2\theta)$$

Rearrange to form a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$ whose roots will be $\tan\alpha,\tan\beta$

Now Vieta's formula and expand $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\implies c\cos\theta-a\sin\theta=b$$

$$\implies c\cos\alpha-a\sin\alpha=c\cos\beta-a\sin\beta$$

$$\iff\dfrac ca=\dfrac{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta}$$

Use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) and then double angle formula for tan

Answer (score 0):

Use  [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution), $\sec\theta=\dfrac{1+t^2}{1-t^2},\tan\theta=\dfrac{2t}{1-t^2}$ where $t=\tan\dfrac\theta2$  to form  a Quadratic equation in $t$

Now use Now Vieta's formula to find $\tan\dfrac{\alpha+\beta}2$ & then use double angle formula for tan