# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy the given equation, then prove the given expression.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two different values of $\theta$ which satisfy the equation

$bc. \cos(\theta) \cos (\phi)+ac.\sin(\theta) \sin (\phi)=ab$,then prove that:

$$(b^2+c^2-a^2) \cos(\alpha) \cos (\beta)+ac. \sin(\alpha) \sin (\beta)=a^2+b^2-c^2$$

I made two quadratic equations, one in $\cos(\theta)$ and other in $\ sin(\theta)$ and find product of roots and then put it in L.H.S. of what needs to be proved but value of $\cos(\alpha) \cos (\beta)$ and $\sin(\alpha) \sin (\beta)$ are complicated and it is not giving desired result. Could someone suggest any alternate approach,

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490652/prove-that-tan-alpha-beta-2ac-a2-c2

Comment: Are you sure about the coefficient of $sin(\alpha)sin(\beta)$? I guess it should be $c^2+a^2-b^2$. Because I just checked your equation using $\phi$=45degrees, $a=1/2, b=1/2, c=1$. The values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will come out to be 105 degrees and 345 degrees. They are not satisfying the equation you have mentioned to be proved.